# Make a div slide while another div's height changes

Tags: jquery, css, events, height

I'm trying to get a div to follow his fellow div's lowest border while it changes heights. There are several events that make the height change, and I'm considering adding the function to all of those. However it isn't working as intended. Here is some code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="resForm">
        <div href class="bookCommentsToggle">Click Here</div>
        <div class="bookComments"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="adjustPriceHeight"></div>
    <div class="machine-right"></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background:#ccc;
}
#resForm {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    background:yellow;
}
.bookCommentsToggle {
    height:50px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.bookComments {
    width:100px;
    height:300px;
    background:red;
    display:none;
}
.machine-right {
    float:right;
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    background:blue;
}
.adjustPriceHeight {
    width:200px;
    background:#fff;
    float:right;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function adjustPriceH() {
    var totalHeight = $('#resForm').outerHeight(),
        priceHeight = $('.machine-right').outerHeight(),
        pushPrice = totalHeight - priceHeight;

    $('.adjustPriceHeight').css('height', pushPrice).slideDown('slow');
}

$('.bookCommentsToggle').click(function () {
    $('.bookComments').slideToggle('slow', function(){
        adjustPriceH();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZeNz0r/saY8g/)

I'm would like `.machine-right` to move as the `#resForm` adjusts it's size. I feel I'm close, but not quite there yet.

Hoping to see one of those one-liner solutions I usually get from SO experts, happy coding^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**by not trying to execute on a callback; .slideToggle(duration, *callback*)**

that makes it wait until the slide is done before it fires the animation; which you need it to do to get the height calcs the way it's set up.

**if the heights are always the same**

So instead, give `.bookComments` & `.adjustPriceHeight` the same height and `display:none`, and slide them both at the same time. You'll just need to add `clear:right` to `.machine-right` and you jquery turns into:

```
$('.bookCommentsToggle').on('click', function () {
    $('.bookComments, .adjustPriceHeight').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/7xEUZ/

**if the heights will vary**

You'll need to remove `slideDown` from your function to prevent jittering from the conflicting commands.

```
function aph() {
    var th = $('#resForm').outerHeight(),
        ph = $('.machine-right').outerHeight(),
        pp = th - ph;
    $('.adjustPriceHeight').height(pp);//no need for css or slideDown here
}

//like @mainguy suggests, cause he's awesome
$('.bookCommentsToggle').on('click', function () {
    $('.bookComments').stop().slideToggle({ progress:aph }, 'slow');
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/h5c4U/

Comment: Thats even more onelinerish than my answer. Cool:-)

Comment: Though either way he should have `clear:right` on `.machine-right` since that the intent.

Comment: Your answer is based on the premise that `.bookComments` and `.adjustPriceHeight` have the same height, but there are several events that change `#resForm`'s height. On the other hand this is a clean solution for other situations that I have. +1 on going for the one-liner and +1 (again if i could) for cleaning the css. I didn't know about `clear:right;` going to read up on that.

Comment: @FiLeVeR10 Dam, that means I was so close to getting it right. I had this `$('.adjustPriceHeight').height(pushPrice).slideDown('slow');` a couple of hours ago. If only I had thought that the animation's steps would take care of the problem. Cheers that's perfect. Switching correct answer to you, out of completeness and jitter free  solution.

Answer (score 2):

Do your updates in the progress callback.

```
    $('.bookCommentsToggle').click(function () {
        $('.bookComments').slideToggle(
            {
                progress:adjustPriceH
            }, 'slow');
    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aBhQE/)

Comment: I'm getting some sort of error applying this, where the last few steps of the animation aren't being accounted for, so there's a gap, as the objects don't align as they do on your fiddle. I fixed it by adding a second call to `adjustPriceH` on the `complete` callback, but it doesn't seem pretty. Yours is the correct answer though... it's probably a div I can't see that's messing the result. +1